# Compare two strings from line in txt file

Tags: php

I have a txt file which contains a few pieces of information which include, amoung other things, a name a password. From a form submission I need to check if the password matches the name, I really suck at txt files, but this works:

```
    function checkPassword($password, $username){
        $userinfo = file_get_contents(USER_INFO); 
        $uniqueinfo = explode("-", $userinfo);
        if (in_array($password, $uniqueinfo) && in_array($username, $uniqueinfo)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now, as you've probably guessed this will return true as long as a valid username and password are found, even if they don't belong to the same account. So you can get this to return true if you enter a password from a different account. Not good. So, I tried:

```
    function checkPassword($password, $username){
        $userinfo = file_get_contents(USER_INFO); 
        foreach($userinfo as $uniqueinfo) {
            $uniqueinfo = explode("-", $uniqueinfo);
            if (in_array($password, $uniqueinfo) && in_array($username, $uniqueinfo)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this just returns false even with valid credentials. Not sure where I'm going wrong here so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, unless the password and username match the first item in the file your function will return false. Try something like:

```
function checkPassword($password, $username){
        $userinfo = file_get_contents(USER_INFO);
        if(!$userinfo){
            echo "Failed to open file!";
            return false;
        }
        $bits = explode('-',$userInfo);
        for($x = 0; $x < count($bits);$x+=2){
            $testPass = $bits[$x];
            $testUser = $bits[$x+1];
            if ($username == $testUser && $password == $testPass) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This will only return false if no item in the file matches.

Comment: That still returns false with valid credentials.

Comment: This is a line in the file: Njnjnj-Nnnono-username-password-jjijiii@sss.com

Comment: Aah. I was assuming each entry was on it's own line. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That still won't work. Also, you need a second argument for the explode.

Comment: Added a check on the file.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. This works perfectly! (except you forgot to camel case the first file variable).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20963/discussion-between-tom-and-jim)

Answer (score 1):

**A.** `file_get_contents` returns string not array use `file` instead

```
  $userinfo = file_get_contents(USER_INFO); 
                      ^--------------------- string not array
```

therefore `foreach($userinfo as $uniqueinfo) {` would not work also

**B.** Use `checkPassword($username,$password)` and not checkPassword($password,$username) for clarity

**C.** use `trim` to remove white spaces before verification

Modified Function

```
function checkPassword($username,$password) {
    $userinfo = file(USER_INFO);
    foreach ( $userinfo as $uniqueinfo ) {
        list($user, $pass) = array_map("trim",explode("-", $uniqueinfo));
        if ($username == $user && $password == $pass) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That still returns false with valid credentials.

Comment: Not trues ... tested it my self please note that am using `checkPassword($username,$password)` . .username before password and also the text format is like this http://pastebin.com/WM7HJZ5L

Comment: How did you define `USER_INFO` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What happens if you print out $username, $user, $pass and $password in the loop?

Comment: @Baba  define("USER_INFO", "files/userinfo.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you like your code just add a flag and return based on that.

```
function checkPassword($password, $username){
    $userinfo = file_get_contents(USER_INFO); 
    $lines = explode("\n", $userinfo);
    foreach($lines as $uniqueinfo) {
        if (strstr($uniqueinfo, $password) && strstr($uniqueinfo, $username)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For some reason this returns false even with valid credentials.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your lines have in them.  Maybe your newlines are not showing up and the whole thing is treated as one big line.

Comment: This is a line in the file: Njnjnj-Nnnono-username-password-jjijiii@sss.com